# Entity Framework Core many to many design problem

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

the idea is that some kind of entity may have many images and images may be linked to many entities. In addition each many-to-many relationship has a number for an ordering position.
So here is what my code looks like:

```
public abstract class X {
    public int Id{get; private set;}
    public ICollection<ImageLink> ImageLinks{ get; } = new HashSet<ImageLink>();
    ...
}

public class A : X {
    ...
}

public class B : X {
    ...
}

public class <MANY OTHER CLASSES> : X {
    ...
}


public class ImageLink {
    public int EntityId { get; protected set; }
    public int ImageId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual X Entity { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; protected set; }
    public int Position { get; private set; }
    ....
}
```

I would like my ef core model to have this kind of inheritance because I don't want to repeat some partial views/controllers code and because it makes sense to me.
I know I can't do this because the image link entity will be mapped in a single table but I need a table for each many-to-many relationship.

Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/ef-core-many-to-many-relationship/)

Comment: Probably you need an intermediate auxiliary table, or specify in your ImageLink entity a collection of X, that will generate the table for you, normally the auxiliary table for many to many is an ID, Id_X, Id_ImagenLink

Comment: Yet another instance of the *polymorphic associations* question.

Comment: This would probably work with Table-per-Hierarchy inheritance (where all subclasses are stored in a single table with a discriminator) but it won't work with Table-per-Type. Even in SQL-land this is a hack where the "EntityId" cannot establish a relationship to any one of the actual related tables without an additional discrininator. Honestly, keep it simple. What's the real difference between {n} linking tables containing their respective rows, or 1 linking table servicing *all* those rows, and later dealing with all potential reasons for change? (I.e. ImageLink improvements for "B" alone?)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a different image table per entity if you use [owned entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types)

Now, I couldn't get the navigation property to work from `ImageLink` to `X`, but it might be possible to do with generics or something.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<A>().OwnsMany(a => a.ImageLinks, e =>
    {
        e.ToTable("ImageLinksForA");
        e.WithOwner();
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<B>().OwnsMany(a => a.ImageLinks, e =>
    {
        // Letting EF pick a table name for me
        e.WithOwner();
    });
    
    // Repeat for each descendent of X
}
```